# Determine whether the sequence $\left(\int_{1}^{n} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\, dx\right)_n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question about how to prove if the sequence converges. The general term for sequence is $$a_n = \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,  dx.$$
I have problems to see what is happening if you can be specific and do step by step, i would be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your series converges

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner This is a very useless comment, regardless of whether it's true. Have you not read the part "if you can be specific and do step by step"? And where did you pick the word "series" to begin with -- this is about a **sequence**, especially as the series $\sum_n a_n$ happily diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\lvert a_n\rvert \leq \int_{1}^n \frac{\lvert \sin^2 x\rvert}{x^2}\, dx \leq \int_{1}^n \frac{dx}{x^2} = 1-\frac{1}{n}\leq 1$$
so your sequence is **bounded**.

Clearly, it is also **non-decreasing**, as $a_{n+1}-a_n = \int_n^{n+1} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\, dx \geq 0$ (the integral of a non-negtive function is non-negative).

So you have a bounded, non-decreasing sequence; by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), it must converge.

Comment: Just a semantic question: why do you say non-decreasing instead of increasing?

Comment: @infinitylord I proved $a_{n+1}\geq a_n$ for all $n$, not $a_{n+1} > a_n$. This only shows (using the discutable, but standard English terminology) that the sequence is non-decreasing — not that it is increasing. (Same difference as what in English is a non-negative vs. positive number.)

Comment: Interesting. The way I was taught, we would say increasing instead of non-decreasing, and say strictly increasing otherwise.

Comment: @infinitylord Same here (French education). English has other, mysterious conventions.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks a lot. Your explanation helps a lot.

Comment: Glad this helped.